# allow/deny external request htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block Flash/SWF uploaded by my users from calling other domains(unless approved).

I only want to block only a few domains in which I think is malicious.

Answer (score 0):

```
# List the domains here, put [NC, OR] at the end of
# each domain rule except the last one.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.invalid [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.org
RewriteRule .*\.swf http://localhost [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i keep getting hacked by russian domains. is it possible to adapt this to block all requests from the local host to urls containing '.ru' for example?

Comment: @daniel Crabbe That is a separate question. And blocking Russian domains cannot solve your security holes.

Comment: no it doesn't but at least if they do get hacked their scripts wont work and will give me more time to remove the hacks.

Comment: To block access from all russian IP adresses you may use my [prepared blocklist](http://labs.toscho.de/ip-to-cidr/) in your .htaccess. But don’t feel safe just because you use it.